# SSH multiplexing hangs if not gracefully shutdown

Tags: ssh, port-forwarding, ssh-tunnel

I am attempting to set up remote access to my home computer via SSH with multiplexing.  Here is the setup:  from my laptop, I connect to a port on my modem; this port is forwarded to my router, which then forwards it to the local desktop and I authenticate with my key.  Due to multiplexing, I can then open other connection to the home box without needed to re-authenticate.  This all works just as I would expect it to.

However, a problem occurs when I reboot the laptop.  If I reboot, then I can no longer SSH into the home box – attempting to do so hangs for a bit without prompting me to authenticate and then eventually times out.

I can resolve the issue my restarting the home box (though that requires physical presence, which rather defeats the point).  I can also avoid triggering the issue if I disconnect the SSH connection gracefully with `ssh -O exit $IP -p $PORT`.

Given the above, I have two questions:  First, is this intended behavior or have I run into a bug?  And, second, is there any way I can avoid this issue?  Thanks!

(This question is superficially similar to [SSH multiplex timeout configuration](https://serverfault.com/questions/966332/ssh-multiplex-timeout-configuration), but *that* question is about the server being rebooted/unreachable whereas my question is about the client rebooting without gracefully signaling the end of the multiplexed connection.)

[**EDIT**]
As requested in a comment below, here is the (not super helpful) output of attempting to connect with the `-vv` flag.  I have slightly redacted the output by replacing my IP, username and port with `$IP`, $USER`, and`$PORT`, respectively.

```sh
OpenSSH_8.1p1, LibreSSL 3.0.2
debug1: Reading configuration data /home/$USER/.ssh/config
debug1: /home/$USER/.ssh/config line 4: Applying options for *
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug2: resolve_canonicalize: hostname $IP is address
debug1: auto-mux: Trying existing master
debug1: Control socket "/home/$USER/.ssh/$USER@$IP:$PORT" does not exist
debug2: ssh_connect_direct
debug1: Connecting to $IP [$IP] port $PORT.
debug1: connect to address $IP port $PORT: Connection timed out
ssh: connect to host $IP port $PORT: Connection timed out
```

When I don't trigger this bug, (and thus *can* successfully connect), the output with `-vv` is exactly the same, except that the `Connection timed out` line is replaced with a line stating `debug1: Connection established` and the connection then proceeds to authenticate normally.

Here is the entirety of my very basic `.ssh/config` file, in case it is relevant:

```sh
Host *
    ControlMaster auto
    ControlPath   ~/.ssh/%r@%h:%p
    ControlPersist yes
    ServerAliveInterval 300
    ServerAliveCountMax 2
    RemoteForward 9999 localhost:22
```

Comment: Are you sure you are **rebooting** and not just hibernating your laptop? Run `ssh` with the `-vv` option, when the problem occurs and add the output to the question.

Comment: @PiotrP.Karwasz Thanks for the comment.  I have added the output with `-vv` to my question above.

In reply to your question: Yes, I am sure I am rebooting rather than hibernating.  I reboot with the command `sudo reboot` and the laptop goes through the full boot process afterwards. 

After additional testing, it *appears* that terminating the SSH connection with `sudo poweroff` rather than `sudo reboot` does not trigger the bug, but running `sudo poweroff` *after* I have triggered the bug by rebooting does not solve the problem—I have to reboot the home box I'm SSHing into.

Comment: Since you reboot, the `ssh` client gets a `SIGTERM` signal, closes the connection in a clean way and deletes the control socket. So the problem is exactly what it appears to be: a network problem. You have connectivity problems and/or a restrictive firewall is dropping your connection attempt.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After digging into this a bit more (and reading the **excellent** book [SSH Mastery](https://mwl.io/nonfiction/tools#ssh)), I was able to resolve my issue: Even though I had set a `ServerAliveInterval` in my *client* `.ssh/config` file, I had not set a `ClientAliveInterval` in my *server* `sshd_config` file.

As a result, the *server* was not timing out, and was maintaining the connection.  In combination with the double-port-forwarding required to navigate my home network, this was occupying the (only) ports I had opened and preventing additional connections.

Adding a `ClientAliveInterval 10` line to my `sshd_config` file (and remembering to restart the sshd service with `sudo pkill -1 sshd` solves the issue nicely.  Hopefully this info can help others solve this issue quickly.

Comment: Without `ClientAliveInterval` the server will not detect the dead peer until the TCP/IP connection times out (a couple of days). However that should not prevent the server from accepting new connections. Unless it misinterprets the new connection for the old one (same source IP, same source port), which is very unlikely unless you `NAT`'s are not working properly. Can you sketch you scheme of port forwarding?

Comment: @PiotrP.Karwasz Yes, that's it exactly—it appears to be a double NAT problem.  As described in the question, I am connecting to port `XXXX` on my modem, which forwards to port `YYYY` on my router, which forwards to port 22 on the workstation I would like to access.  Checking the workstation's `sshd` access logs, it looks like it is viewing all connections as originating from port XXXX and the modem's local IP.

Comment: If you can, you should switch your modem into _“bridge mode”_ and get rid of one (malfunctioning) NAT: a simple port forwarding should perform a `DNAT` (rewrite the destination address and port), but your modem performs also a `SNAT` (rewrites the source address and port). This certainly solves the [hairpin NAT problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hairpinning), but hides the source address of whoever tries to connect to your home computer, which is bad for auditing (and limits to one your remote connections).

Comment: @PiotrP.Karwasz Thanks for the tip about bridge mode.  I looked into it, but unfortunately my (cable-company-owned) modem does not support bridge mode – for reasons that seem to have more to do with the companies interest than my one.  *sigh*.

On the other hand, although my (valid) connections are having their source address and port rewritten, the _invalid_ login attempts from people banging against the key-based authentication are still reporting IP addresses/ports from outside the local network.  Do you happen to have any idea why they aren't also rewritten?