# Detecting stuck SSH control master sockets

Tags: ssh

I use OpenSSH's [ControlMaster features](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/OpenSSH/Cookbook/Multiplexing) quite a bit to speed up new connections to a few systems which I use heavily.

I have the following in my `~/.ssh/config`:

```
Host *
    ConnectTimeout 7
    ControlMaster auto                   
    ControlPath ~/.ssh/controlmasters/%r@%h:%p
    ControlPersist 10m
```

Generally, this works great. However, there's one major annoyance: if the ControlMaster socket for a host gets “hung” due to a network interruption, `ssh that_host` just **hangs forever**. As far as I can tell, it literally never gives up on the existing ControlMaster socket and tries to create a new one. I have to manually `ssh -O exit that_host` before it will work.

What I really wish I could convince `ssh` to do is give up and tear down the ControlMaster socket if it can't connect within the `ConnectTimeout`.

Is there a missing `ControlMasterConnectTimeout` option which I'm missing? Or some other way I can convince ssh to detect and restart a dead ControlMaster socket?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

**TL;DR**

```
Host *
    ServerAliveInterval 11
```

---

I'm guessing `ConnectTimeout` is not applicable here because the master is already connected.

This is not specific to `ControlMaster` but you could easily apply it just to relevant entries in your config.

You can use two different methods to detect stale connection:

- `TCPKeepAlive` Uses mechanisms in the underlying socket.
- `ServerAliveInterval` (upto `ServerAliveCountMax` consecutive failures)

I like the latter as there might be something else broken/hung that will be picked up and the manual also mentions possibility of spoofing.

Obviously you could choose another number.  This variable in combination with `ServerAliveCountMax` (default 3) will determine when the connection will be dropped so I see things go away in about 33 seconds after i drop my vpn connection (I did not accurately measure this and noticed one session took a bit longer, but I applied this setting globally where maybe I should only apply it to the host I use with `ProxyJump`).